# How to resolve mercurial conflict where no match is found?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I have managed to really get my repo into a state, and I don't have the mad skills required to fix it, your help would be appreciated.

I am trying to merge/update so that the work I developed in a seperate branch is correctly integrated into my local one.

When I run and run a merge on rev 284, I get the following error:

> % hg --repository C:\Projects\foo merge --verbose
>   --tool=internal:merge 284 abort: data/Web/Utilities/Extensions/RegexExtensions.cs.i@364e78cf7bcb: no
>   match found! [command returned code 255 Sat Jan 19 16:12:54 2013]

I am using tortoisehg, and have tried to search for a resolution but I can't figure out how to resolve this error?

What has happend in this case, is that the file has been deleted in one branch, and I guess exists in the other?

How to resovle?

[image: This is what it currenlty looks like].

Edit 1:

Was fiddling around and found this as well:

```
#!python
** Mercurial version (2.4.2).  TortoiseHg version (2.6.2)
** Command: --nofork workbench
** CWD: C:\Projects\foo
** Encoding: cp1252
** Extensions loaded: 
** Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Windows version: sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7600, platform=2, service_pack='')
** Processor architecture: x64
** Qt-4.8.0 PyQt-4.9.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\repowidget.pyo", line 1678, in visualDiffToLocal
  File "tortoisehg\hgqt\visdiff.pyo", line 213, in visualdiff
  File "mercurial\copies.pyo", line 166, in pathcopies
  File "mercurial\copies.pyo", line 151, in _backwardcopies
  File "mercurial\copies.pyo", line 138, in _forwardcopies
  File "mercurial\copies.pyo", line 106, in _tracefile
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 722, in ancestors
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 546, in parents
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 246, in __get__
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 399, in _filenode
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 776, in lookup
LookupError: data/web/Utilities/Extensions/RegexExtensions.cs.i@364e78cf7bcb: no match found
```

Edit 2:

I've managed to merge most of the revisions I need, I am left now with just one on the branch that is corrupt.

How can I now discard that revision/branch?

[image]

Comment: Show `hg heads`, read `hg help merge`: You can't merge with rev. 284, when you are on rev 284. And in TortoiseHG all merges are (can be) performed in GUI

Comment: so ive discovered that the revision 284 seems to be corrupt i can do everything as long as i dont include that one, seems to be related to that missing file. how can i see the changes from the revision? clicking it gives me an error, can i browse to the patch on disk?

Comment: `hg diff -c 284`. And perform `hg verify`

Comment: So i see the changes, but when it hits the lookup error it aborts, is there a way to modify the manifest to exclude that file?

Comment: Please run verify on the repository

Comment: Read [Repository Corruption](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryCorruption) Wiki page

Answer (score 0):

CLI-version of merge (screenshots - maybe later)

```
hg up
hg merge 297
hg commit -m "Merge 1"
hg merge 284
hg commit -m "Merge 2"
```

If you want to merge at some other points: fix destination of update (to this point you'll merge) and merge sources

Comment: thanks so i have merged everything except for those revisions. when i try and do ANYTHING with them, I get the above error, with a lookup error? Can I get the changeset but exclude the file creating the error?

Comment: @shenku - `hg verify` and monitor [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2347/bug-lookuperror) in THG issues-tracker

Comment: Thanx lazy badger, this is definately my issue. How can i discard that problem revision/branch?

Comment: That url is dead.